# Delay no AngularJS utilizado em ariquivo .cshtml

Tags: c#, angularjs

Tenho uma pagina que ao iniciar ela da um daley no checkbox e no campo de texto como na figura abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguem sabe me informar porque isso acontece, e uma possível solução

Comment: É bem difícil de saber qual é o problema sem ver o código.

Comment: Pronto coloquei o codigo inteiro não só da parte da imagem

Comment: Acho que um `ng-cloak` ajuda, mas realmente, não há sentido no uso do AngularJS nessa tela tanto por conta do servidor montar a tela, quanto ao uso errôneo do `two way data binding` do AngularJS sem o uso devido do `ng-model`. Recomendo ler o [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) do AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A causa disso é um tanto óbvia. O HTML sempre é processado linearmente, de cima para baixo.

Desta forma, a marcação HTML está sendo criada antes mesmo de seu *controller* do Angular ter os valores preenchidos. Isto porque, por padrão, a *section scripts* é renderizada no **final do arquivo HTML** (claro que isso pode ter sido alterado, mas tudo indica que é isso mesmo). Se você inspecionar a página pelo *browser* verá isso claramente.

Uma alternativa é processar o item `Indicator` antes do HTML. Ou então, fazer a chamada via AngularJS e tratar tudo por ele mesmo.

A forma que está usando o AngularJS é extremamente incomum, embora não seja nada de outro mundo, é algo que praticamente vai contra a ideia do AngularJS. Seria uma ótima ideia reconsiderar isso e começar a trabalhar da forma indicada ou então abandonar o uso da tecnologia. Afinal, se os dados serão retornados e as *views* serão montadas pelo servidor para que serve o AngularJS?